# one barplot filled with other columns

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a kraken report (metagenomics) like this:

```
df <- data.frame(readsRooted = c(9216, 1248, 1109),
                 taxRank = c("S", "S", "S"),
                 sciName = c("Fusarium falciforme", "Fusarium fujikuroi", "Botrytis cinerea"))

as_tibble(df)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  readsRooted taxRank sciName            
        <dbl> <chr>   <chr>              
1        9216 S       Fusarium falciforme
2        1248 S       Fusarium fujikuroi 
3        1109 S       Botrytis cinerea
```

I want to create a single barplot filled with the `sciName` using the percentage `readsRooted/all readsRooted`. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance. I tried this:

```
ggplot(fam.kreport, aes(x = taxRank, fill = sciName)) + geom_bar()
```

But it gives a plot like this
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvCky.png), filled with `sciName`, true, but the volume of colour of every `sciName` in the bar does not depend of the percentage of readsRooted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In case my post answered your question, you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right. Here is one barplot `fill` by `sciName` showing the percentage `readsRooted/all readsRooted`.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(readsRooted_sum = sum(readsRooted),
         readsRooted_perc = readsRooted/readsRooted_sum)

ggplot(df, aes(x = taxRank, y = readsRooted_perc, fill = sciName)) +  
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat = 'identity')
```

[image]