# One barplot showing the percentages

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have this dataframe:

```
species.kreport <- read.csv(text = 'readsRooted, taxRank, sciName, percentage
9216, S, Fusarium falciforme, 23.05
1248, S,Fusarium fujikuroi, 10.56
1109, S, Botrytis cinerea, 12.69')

species.kreport
#>   readsRooted taxRank              sciName percentage
#> 1        9216       S  Fusarium falciforme      23.05
#> 2        1248       S   Fusarium fujikuroi      10.56
#> 3        1109       S     Botrytis cinerea      12.69
```

I am trying to create a single barplot filled by sciName showing the percentage of every sciName.

I tried this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(species.kreport, aes(x = taxRank, y = percentage, fill = sciName)) +  
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat = 'identity')
```

I want to have plot like this:

[image: The plot I Want to have]

What I have:

[image: legends without plot]

PS: I am using Rstudio!

Thanks in advance
Have a wonderful day!

Comment: You don't say what "perfungalreads" is, but change to "y = percentage/100", should get what you want.

Comment: The question is an extension from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75720801/one-barplot-filled-with-other-columns

Answer (score 0):

If I use

```
ggplot(species.kreport, aes(x = taxRank, y = percentage, fill = sciName)) +  
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat = 'identity')
```

it works.